# I want to make it so that for how high a number is, it gives me a higher value. How do I do that?

Tags: python-3.x

So I want to make it that for how high a number is, the output is higher. I do not know how to do that.

I have done it so for the amount of numbers given, it gets multiplied by 2, but I want it for how high the number is ( 2x2, 4x2) it gives a higher output.

```py
import random

speed = random.randint(1,4)
power = 1
for x in range(speed):
    power *2
    print(power)
```

So I want a random number to be picked from 1 to 4 which is speed. Then I want to multiply it by 2 for how high the value of speed is, for example, if speed is 3, then the power will multiply by 6, so the power then is 18, but what I get is just 1 printed 1-4 times. I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

speed = random.randint(1,4)
power = 1
for x in range(speed):
    p = power *2
    print(p)
```

Assign your equation result as a variable and print that out instead.

Comment: it changed the 1's  from repeating to a bunch of 2's